# How to import Tkinter for distributed Jython jar formed from Python code

Tags: jython

I have tried the steps mentioned at http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/DistributingJythonScripts and formed myapp.jar from my python code and my main.py script uses Tkinter for GUI...but when i try to run it :

java -jar myapp.jar main.py it is showing

import Tkinter, tkFileDialog, tkMessageBox, tempfile, shutil ImportError: No module named Tkinter

How to avoid it....Early response will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Tkinter is not included with Jython, and to the best of my knowledge nobody has ported it.

If you need to do a GUI in Jython, you'll probably need to use a Java library like Swing or SWT.

Comment: Could your perhaps, copy the Tkinter.py file and the _tkinter.so file from the python lib and just put it in the app?

Comment: @DorianDore _tkinter.so is a CPython extension and relies on CPython's symbols and data structures, none of which Jython provides. If it were that easy, they would no doubt have done it.